# While using ddd(display debugger), how can I go back to where execution stopped in the source line after some navigation?

Tags: gdb, ddd-debugger

I use ddd (display debugger) as GUI, and gdb as the internal debugger.
I think I knew this but I can't remember how I did this.
At a breakpoint, sometimes I do 'up' and scroll the source window. Then I want to go back to where I was. (the next line to be executed, with the execution mark standing..)
How can I do this?  (Of course if I do 'next', I can go there, but I want to go there without executing the next line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 'bt'(back-trace) to see the stack state. also you can use 'frame' to see stack frame. **if you type-in 'frame' you'll go to where you were**. you can go to any specific frame by 'frame n' command.